# Independent variables of the inner energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

in thermodynamics the free energy is a function of the volume V and the temperature T. These two variables are called independent. On the other hand on can find the volume and the temperature as a part of the ideal gas equation, which means that they are related to each other.
Therefore I dont understand, why they are named independent.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: The ideal gas law tells us that temperature and volume are uniquely related to one another *only if  pressure is constant.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal gas equation links the temperature volume and pressure, so it allows you to determine *one* of these parameters in terms of the other two. So we can consider the ideal gas equation as determining the pressure in terms of volume and temperature, leaving $T$ and $V$ independent.